# Pandas multi labeled data to heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, heatmap

I have the following data structure:

[image]

Each row represents one annotation. If the user labeled the data with labels 2 and 3 (see second row aka row index 1) than the dataset would be 1 1 0 0 0 0 0.

I would like to make a heatmap out of this, in order to see which labels are closely annotated. The resulting df i believe should be 7x7.(i've tried with np.corrcoef, i've tried pivoting the data, it might be just that i'm not asking the question right.)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

The first 5 rows of data:

```
df = [{'L3': 1},
 {'L2': 1, 'L3': 1},
 {'L7': 1},
 {'L1': 1, 'L4': 1},
 {'L1': 1, 'L2': 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Hi, it's hard to copy data from an image. Also, `np.corr` doesn't exist. Also, you didn't say what went wrong with your attempts. Also, are you looking for `df.corr()`?

Comment: @Neither hi, thanks! i've edited the question. Np.corrcoef of df.corr return a 7x7 array filled with nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `corr` after replacing `nan` by 0 else you get a matrix filled with `nan`:

```
corr = df.fillna(0).corr()
print(corr)
plt.colormesh(corr)
plt.show()

# Output
          L1        L2        L3        L4        L5        L6        L7
L1  1.000000  0.010929 -0.011707 -0.000469 -0.024428 -0.004918  0.033066
L2  0.010929  1.000000 -0.028859 -0.012876 -0.000667  0.009042 -0.017563
L3 -0.011707 -0.028859  1.000000 -0.033609  0.017446  0.036202  0.018763
L4 -0.000469 -0.012876 -0.033609  1.000000 -0.035363 -0.009639  0.038593
L5 -0.024428 -0.000667  0.017446 -0.035363  1.000000  0.007565 -0.045324
L6 -0.004918  0.009042  0.036202 -0.009639  0.007565  1.000000 -0.009466
L7  0.033066 -0.017563  0.018763  0.038593 -0.045324 -0.009466  1.000000
```

[image]

For a quick view, you can use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) but if you want to produce beautiful output, I recommend you to install and use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 2000

np.random.seed(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.NaN, 1], (N, 7), p=[.7, .3]),
                  columns=[f'L{i}' for i in range(1, 8)])
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?